# Difference between acf and cor correlations

Tags: r, correlation

I try to replicate the results from acf() with manually using cor(), and I get differences which I cannot understand.
Consider the following toy example:

```
# two slightly different lines, with a bit of noise
# both are casted into time series
foo <- ts(seq(1:20) + rnorm(20))
bar <- ts((1.5*seq(1:20)-1) + rnorm(20))
foobar=cbind(foo, bar)

# lagged (auto)correlations, up to a lag of 10
pippo <- acf(foobar, 10)

# look at the results; I see the two 'slices' of the resulting
#   datacube: [ , , 1] and [ , , 2]. So far, so good.
pippo$acf

# 1st slice: [1,1,1] = 1 (obviously), and
#   [2,1,1] = 0.82796109 (autocorrelation of foo with itself, lagged 1)

# but if I do:
cor(foobar[1:19, 1], foobar[2:20, 1])
> [1] 0.9669717
```

obviously, 0.82796109 is quite different from 0.9669717,
and I cannot understand why. The same happens with cross-correlation
between the two time series, one lagged with respect to the other.
Even taking into account the
(n-1/n) unbiased/biased factor that sometimes creeps in.
What am I missing here?

Many thanks in advance to whomever wants to help. And my apologies
in advance if my question should come from a lack of understanding.
Luca

Environment: R 4.1.12, running on Win7

Comment: I would suggest reading further information about `acf()`. In the function description it states that `For type = "correlation" and "covariance", the estimates are based on the sample covariance. (The lag 0 autocorrelation is fixed at 1 by convention.)` and that Venables, W. N. and Ripley, B. D. (2002) Modern Applied Statistics with S. Fourth Edition. Springer-Verlag contains the exact definitions used.

Comment: many thanks to @JKupzig for his/her kind answer. My point is, acf() has "correlation" as default; correlation between two variables is, basically, the covariance divided by the product of the two variables' standard deviations. Indeed, cov() on my toy example gives something like 28.something (i.e., not-normalized), which makes me think that acf() should have indeed provided the 'true' correlation. I admittedly didn't check yet on the Venables-Ripley reference.